# JAXB validation returning non-required fields

Tags: json, jaxb, xsd

I am validating a Java object using the Validator API.  THis works as far as telling me that the object is not valid according to the schema, but it gives a very vague error message that one of the elements from a list of all the element's properties are missing.

Schema (truncated for clarity):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1" xmlns:snt="http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="contactInsert">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="suffix" type="snt:stringType255"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="firstName" type="snt:stringType255"
                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="lastName" type="snt:stringType255"
                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="companyID" type="snt:idType" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="companyLocationID" type="snt:idType"
                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="workPhone" type="snt:phoneType"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="cellPhone" type="snt:phoneType"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="homePhone" type="snt:phoneType"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="otherPhone" type="snt:phoneType"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
```

I am basically deserializing a JSON object to the JAXB generated class from the schema above.  Again this works:

```
ValidationErrorHandler errorHandler = null;

        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContactInsert.class);
            JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, contactInsert);

            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory
                    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(ContactInsert.class
                    .getResource("/xsd/v1_1/contact.xsd"));

            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            errorHandler = new ValidationErrorHandler();
            validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

            validator.validate(source);
```

My JSON object gets converted to the ContactInsert instance:

```
{ "companyID":666, "lastName":"dsadasd", "companyLocationID":23950, "otherComments":null }
```

I would expect the validation error to be that "firstName" is expected, however it lists every element from the schema, even though these are not required (minOccurs=0 and not annotated with @Required in the generated Java class:

> "cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'contactInsert' is not
>   complete. One of
>   '{"http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":suffix,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":firstName,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":workPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":cellPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":homePhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":otherPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":faxPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":email,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":isDesignate,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":isActive,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":mainSponsorID,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":hidePercentSafeFlag,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":externalContactID,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":useAsARef,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":positionTitle,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":otherComments,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":formerCompanyID,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":industryStartDate,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":employmentStartDate}' is
>   expected."

Is it possible to configure the validator to only report the required field ("firstName").  I am relatively new to JAXB, but it seems like that error message is not accurate, and that JAXB is simply taking the easy way out by saying one of the elements is missing, but I will not tell you which.

Comment: That error message is coming from the `Validator`, in this use case JAXB is simply the `Source`.

Comment: OK...but why does validator report all those fields in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

### Where is the Error Coming From

The error message being returned is from the `javax.xml.validation.Validator` and not JAXB.  In this use case JAXB is simply the XML source.  If you swapped in a `StAXSource` the StAX parser wouldn't become responsible for the schema validation.

### Is it a Good Error?

> OK...but why does validator report all those fields in the error
>   message?

Here is the error you are getting:

> "cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'contactInsert' is not
>   complete. One of
>   '{"http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":suffix,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":firstName,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":workPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":cellPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":homePhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":otherPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":faxPhone,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":email,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":isDesignate,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":isActive,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":mainSponsorID,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":hidePercentSafeFlag,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":externalContactID,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":useAsARef,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":positionTitle,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":otherComments,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":formerCompanyID,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":industryStartDate,
>   "http://predictivesolutions.com/schema/v1_1":employmentStartDate}' is
>   expected."

This implementation has chosen to list all of the possible elements that may occur here.  If only the required elements where listed someone could have opened a question similar to this one as to why the optional elements were omitted.